# Select query filtering by datediff

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, where-clause

I am trying to write a query where I am filtering by date and also by age , the query would be something like

```
select * 
  from table1 
 where birthdate >= 'date1' 
   and dead <= 'date2' 
 where age >17 
   and <55;
```

The table columns is like this

> ID---name---lastname---birthdate---deadDate

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: filter by dates and age

Comment: `and age>17 and age<55` not `where ...` ... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is really close. However, any time you want multiple conditions in a WHERE clause, you just have to use AND (or OR) in between each. Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE birthdate >= 'date1' AND death <= 'date2' AND age > 17 AND age < 55;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table1 
where birthdate >= 'date1' 
and deadDate <= 'date2' 
and  DATEDIFF(birthdate,deadDate)  between > 17 and < 55;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
select * from table1 where birthdate BETWEEN 'date1' and 'date2 and age > 17 and age < 55
```

The BETWEEN function will compare birthdate field against dates including them in the range.

PD: I strongly suggest make more effort and research before posting a question.